# Jetpack compose UI support for different screen sizes and Image crop from the top

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, screen-size, image-cropper, android-jetpack-compose-ui

[image]

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.background),
            contentDescription = null,
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))

        Text(
            text = "This is a text",
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        Button(onClick = {}) {
            Text(
                text = "Button",
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))

    }
}
```

I have a UI and sample code as above. I need to make some modifications to support that to small screens as below guidelines.

- **1** and **3** areas height is 12.dp
- **2** area minimum height should be 12.dp on small screens and height will be increased to fill the screen if there's space on large screens
- On all screens, even small images (portrait type) should match to width (keeping the image's original aspect ratio) and the extra height of the image from the top as **4** area should be cropped on small screens.

How can do this?

Comment: First, depending on the smallest screen's border you need to decide what should be desired height of your image. Then you could search for code that crop image from bottom.